# How do you untar multiple files into multiple subdirectory based on filename

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, tar

I have a single tar file containing about 19 million files (no folders)

```
0000107b869682826003b04a40e6394.txt
00029237482s8923789423ud8923892.txt
2c002y8378723887292377a79237649.txt
f598238209237408238742308374038.txt
```

how do I untar all the files such that they appear in subdirectories named after the first four chars of the files. So for the example above, it would create `0000`, `2c02`, and `f599` directories and each would have the following files.

```
0000\0000107b869682826003b04a40e6394.txt
0002\00029237482s8923789423ud8923892.txt
2c02\2c002y8378723887292377a79237649.txt
f598\f598238209237408238742308374038.txt
```

I've already tried creating a script that goes through the files in the tar file, creates a directory and extracts that file from the tar and puts it in the directory. This works for small number of files, but when the tar has millions, extracting takes a really long time.

Answer (score 9):

With GNU `tar` and its `s` command with syntax from `sed`. I switched from `s///` to `s|||`.

```
tar -xvf file.tar --transform 's|\(....\).*|\1/&|' --show-transformed-names
```

Comment: LOL - a more elegant solution indeed :-D But talking about 19mil files it's still going to take time :-)

Comment: ..nice dog bro!

Answer (score 0):

I created a test tarball, no directories:

```
pg@TREX:~/test$ tar -tvf test.tar | rev | cut -c -8 | rev
0001.txt
0002.txt
0003.txt
0004.txt
0005.txt
0011.txt
0012.txt
0013.txt
0014.txt
0015.txt
0021.txt
0022.txt
0023.txt
0024.txt
0025.txt
```

I run this script (tartest.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

tar -xf tarfile.tar
i=$(ls *.txt | cut -c -3 | sort | uniq) 
echo "$i" >> directory_list 
mkdir $i 
while read line; do mv $line*.txt $line/; done < directory_list
```

Result:

```
pg@TREX:~/test$ tree
.
├── 000
│   ├── 0001.txt
│   ├── 0002.txt
│   ├── 0003.txt
│   ├── 0004.txt
│   └── 0005.txt
├── 001
│   ├── 0011.txt
│   ├── 0012.txt
│   ├── 0013.txt
│   ├── 0014.txt
│   └── 0015.txt
├── 002
│   ├── 0021.txt
│   ├── 0022.txt
│   ├── 0023.txt
│   ├── 0024.txt
│   └── 0025.txt
├── directory_list
├── tartest.sh
└── test.tar
```

I'm sure this'll take a bit of time with 19mil files, and I'm sure more elegant solutions exist... but seems to do what you asked :-)

Comment: This could fail with 19 million files: `ls *.txt`

Comment: Yeah, if all the files don't have .txt extension, as described on OP:s question. However it should work without the extension, creating a direcory "tar" and moving tarfile itself there - along with any other file beginning with those characters :-) Or do you see a problem with using ls in the first place? Anyway, I prefer your one-liner - I didn't even know sed can be tied with tar that way :-)

Comment: I assume that if `bash` replaces `*.txt` with 19 million file names, that `bash` will then output `argument list too long`.

Comment: Oh, that didn't occur to me at all. And in keeping with Mr Murphy's legacy, that'd be bound to happen around file 18 699 453 :-D

Comment: You can just replace it with `ls | egrep '\.txt$' | ...`

Comment: This starts by untarring into a flat directory.  That's super not great, especially for some filesystems where a directory can't shrink.  ext3/4 is like that, unless it change recently.  After you do this, you're going to want to make a new version of this directory and `mv` all the numbered subdirs into it so the directory containing them isn't unreasonably large.  And BTW, GNU `tar --transform` isn't actually running `/usr/bin/sed` (or fork/exec at all), it's just the same command *language* on filenames.

Comment: ... not to mention that I'm creating two unnecessary files. You can power up a car with a steam engine, but it's not the most efficient way of getting it running. Thanks for the sed clarification :-)

Comment: Also, it fails to quote some shell vars while expanding them, so a tar containing a filename like `1 bxyz...` could get both `1` and `b` created as directory names.  Not obviously exploitable, although you can get all the `1*` files written to `1/` defeating the splitting, and even all the `b*` files written to `b/` which wasn't the first character of this filename.  Since you're using bash anyway you could use an array variable, but that just moves the problem of word-splitting into the array initializer.  I guess use `IFS=$'\n'`, although malicious .tar files could have newline filenames.

Comment: Using a bash array like `dirlist = (  $((ls | cut | sort -u)) )` would let you loop over it without a tmp file, since you're using bash anyway not just POSIX `sh`.

Comment: Thanks again. I try to keep things POSIX, but most often end up with one sort of bashism or another :-)